alternative to get timestamp faster instead of const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(result.blockNumber).timestamp;
i am subscribing to logs using web3.eth for live events from blockchain and need timestamp of that event but this function takes delay
const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(result.blockNumber);
const timestamp = block.timestamp;
can you tell any fast alternative to this.
thankyou!

currentTimestamp = new Date();
will give you the exact timestamp when you called new Date()

no but i want the time when txn happened that is why i used block number .Your method will give current time only .

hmm how long delay are you speaking? are you using public endpoint or paid?
